# distribution of non-central chi random sample

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

Suppose that $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is a random sample from a non-central chi distribution with $1$ degree of freedom. What is the distribution of the sample variance of $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n$?